# Is this the correctly whay to calculate the composition of linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T_{1}(x,y)=(y,x)$ and $T_{2}(x,y)=(x,0)$ Linear transformations

Is this the correctly whay to calculate the composition of linear transformation?

$(T_{1}\circ T_{2})_{(x,y)}=T_{1}(T_{2}(x,y))=T_{1}(x,0)=(0,x)$

$(T_{2}\circ T_{1})_{(x,y)}=T_{2}(T_{1}(x,y))=T_{2}(y,x)=(y,0)$

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for review @AlexVong